# Use the same cell for table view and collection view

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uikit

So I have a few collection views that use the same cell (which basically looks like table view but for my purposes, I need to use the collection view). In the newest feature I am using tableView and cell for it looks the same, so is there a way to use the same cell for that view too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply, no. A TableViewCell is of type `UITableViewCell` which is very different from `UICollectionViewCell`.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing it's a little bit late for an answer, but better late than never, right?

In contrast to [Timmy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72431295/21406056) answer, and following [Amal's and Gokul's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41770019/21406056) answer, I was able to build a reusable cell for both `UITableView` and `UICollectionView` with the help of `XIB` files. Unfortunately, due to UIKit's class inheritance, we cannot make our custom cells inherit from both `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`, so the key thing is to create your `XIB` and use it inside a cell as a Custom View. This way, you're able to reuse your view for both scenarios.

In my case, I needed to code the Apple Music app using Interface Builder/Storyboards. Some components were reused by other views, so I decided to create a XIB for them. These were the steps that helped me create a reusable view for both a `UITableView` and a `UICollectionView`:

1. Start by designing your `XIB`, whether by Interface Builder/Storyboards or programmatically. There are a lot of tutorials out there. Specifically, I used this [one](https://betterprogramming.pub/swift-3-creating-a-custom-view-from-a-xib-ecdfe5b3a960).
2. With your `XIB` ready, place it inside your `TableViewCell` or `CollectionViewCell`. Don't forget to set the custom class of your view to match your `XIB`, otherwise this won't work.
3. With your cell ready, what's left now is to `dequeue` it in your `cellForRow at` or `cellForItem at` in your tableView/collectionView data source method and customize it as you wish.

Hope this helps :D